# Grouping elements with same date in a custom ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have a custom *ArrayList* where some objects have same date, so I want to merge them into a single object if their date is same, such that for each unique date there is only one item.

I have tried the following but it does not work as intended.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> getaardata()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.clear();

    for(int i=0;i<CallLogger.arrContactDetails.size()-1;i++)
    {
        for (int k = i+1; k < CallLogger.arrContactDetails.size(); k++)
        {
            String dateCurrnt = Util.convertStringToDate(
                CallLogger.arrContactDetails.get(i).getDate());
            String dateCurrntNew = Util.convertStringToDate(
                CallLogger.arrContactDetails.get(k).getDate());

            if(dateCurrnt.equalsIgnoreCase(dateCurrntNew)){
                arr.add(Integer.parseInt(
                    CallLogger.arrContactDetails.get(i).getSmsCount()) + 
                    Integer.parseInt(CallLogger.arrContactDetails.get(k).getSmsCount()));
            }
            else
            {
                arr.add(Integer.parseInt(
                    CallLogger.arrContactDetails.get(k).getSmsCount())); 
            }
        }
    }
    Log.e("logtag", ""+arr.size());
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Use a set and define equality on your objects based on your criteria, then override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods appropriately. Done.

Comment: Can you help me with some examples or code snippet

Comment: Start by reading up on what a `Set` interface is and specifically the `HashSet` implementation class, then everything will be clear. Only remaining thing is to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` which there are thousands of articles explaining.

Comment: Yes thank you  ,but my inner loop is not right ,i want to compare every element with every other element in the array so that elements having same date club together and become a single entity,but here if my array size is 21,it gives 210 elements in the final array

Answer (score 1):

```
if(dateCurrnt.equalsIgnoreCase(dateCurrntNew)){
    arr.set(i, Integer.parseInt(
        CallLogger.arrContactDetails.get(i).getSmsCount()) + 
        Integer.parseInt(CallLogger.arrContactDetails.get(k).getSmsCount()));
}
else
{
    arr.add(Integer.parseInt(CallLogger.arrContactDetails.get(k).getSmsCount())); 
}
```

Comment: my inner looping is not correct,it adding duplicate elements in the final array.can you throw some light

Comment: It's because you always call "arr.add(...)", I've changed it to: if dateCurrnt is equal to dateCurrntNew, call arr.set(index, object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashMap<String, Integer>`, where `String`represents `date`field in string form & `Integer`represents `smsCount`field.

With this, you don't need to run a loop inside loop. Only one for loop will work.

```
String dateCurrnt = Util.convertStringToDate(
            CallLogger.arrContactDetails.get(i).getDate());

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
if (map.contains(dateCurrnt)) {
  //get the value & add the new smsCount to it & set it
} else {
  //put the value in map (first time)
  map.put(dateCurrnt, Integer.parseInt(
                CallLogger.arrContactDetails.get(i).getSmsCount()));
}
```

Comment: nice,but how to get  the position  of the object which has the same date as the current in loop, i want one object per date and merge al sms count particular to that date if (map.contains(dateCurrnt)) {
  //get the value & add the new smsCount to it & set it
}